# want to change like button to default state when user clicks unlike button and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created two buttons with a text. So that user can select like or unlike against it. For example, Text can be 'Good car' and there are like and unlike (2 buttons) with this. If user clicks like button , like button turns grey (by default it is green) and now if user selects unlike button then like button should turn to default state automatically on clicking unlike. As both buttons shouldn't be selected at same time. I don't know how to do that in html/javascript/jquery etc. Please help..

code is:

```
<span class="tags">Good Car  <i id="b1" onclick="myfunc(this)" 
class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> <i onclick="myfunc1(this)" 
class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></span>


<script>
function myfunc(x)
{


    if (x.style.color==="green") 
    {
        x.style.color="grey"
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.color="green"
    }
}

function myfunc1(x)
{


    if (x.style.color==="red") 
    {
        x.style.color="grey"
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.color="red"
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!-- give an id to both buttons -->
<span class="tags">Good Car <i id="b1" onclick="myfunc(this)" class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> <i id="b2" onclick="myfunc1(this)" class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></span>

<script>
  function myfunc(x) {
    if (x.style.color === "green") {
      x.style.color = "grey";
      document.getElementById("b2").style.color = "red"; // get the other button and set its color
    } else {
      x.style.color = "green";
    }
  }

  function myfunc1(x) {
    if (x.style.color === "red") {
      x.style.color = "grey";
      document.getElementById("b1").style.color = "green"; // get the other button and set its color
    } else {
      x.style.color = "red";
    }
  }
</script>
```

An alternative solution that uses jQuery and no ids is.

```
<span class="tags">Good Car  
<i class="green thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i>
<i class="red thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
</span>

<style>
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // execute this code after page has loaded
    // register a click event listener for anything that has the class "green" or "red"
    $(document).on("click", ".green,.red", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("green")) { // if they clicked on the green button, see if it is NOT active
            if (!$(this).hasClass("gray")) {
                $(".red").removeClass("gray"); // we are going to become active, so turn off the other button (it might already be off, but that is ok)
            }
        } else { // must be red
            if (!$(this).hasClass("gray")) { // if they clicked on the red button, see if it is NOT active
                $(".green").removeClass("gray");// we are going to become active, so turn off the other button (it might already be off, but that is ok)
            }
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("gray"); // flip the active state of this button
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what the issue with their code is, and how this solves the  problem. Remember that we're here to educate, not just to dump code. Also note that giving each icon it's own `id` attribute is not a very ideal solution. You now need to ensure they are all unique within the HTML and also repeat the two `myfunN()` functions for every icon.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this would be to set the default grey state in CSS. Then you can add or remove a class from the icons as you click them to set their own colours. This way the UI logic is kept separate from the JS.

Also note that you should not be using the `on*` event attributes. They should be avoided wherever possible. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. To remove the class from the sibling icon you can use `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling` respectively. Here's a full working example:

```js
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbsup, .thumbsdown');
Array.from(thumbs).forEach((thumb) =>
{
  thumb.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.previousElementSibling && this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    this.nextElementSibling && this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.thumbsup,
.thumbsdown {
  color: grey;
}
.thumbsup.active {
  color: green;
}
.thumbsdown.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<span class="tags">
  Good Car  
  <i class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
  <i class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
</span><br />

<span class="tags">
  Foo Bar  
  <i class="thumbsup fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
  <i class="thumbsdown fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Many thanks Rory McCrossan, it worked. Thank you so much for helping me so quickly :)

Comment: Another thing that i want to do is that i want to capture that whether user liked or disliked and then add that number in the field in DB . For example, for this tag DB has two columns like and unlike , like column keeps the count that how many people liked against this tag and dislike do the vice versa. There is a submit button on the screen as well. On clicking submit, i want to capture that whether user liked or disliked and then want to save in DB. I am using Php.I am not sure how i can capture this value in java script and then pass to php to save in DB.Please suggest if you have idea.